# How to prove that the erosion of a convex set by a convex set will result in a convex set?

Tags: image-processing

How to prove that given convex sets A and B, the [erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) of A by B will result in C - a convex set, too?

I was given this question as a test-preparation, and I think it shuold be a proof, but I don't know how to prove it.

A convex set is a set where every line connecting 2 dots in the set, must be part of the set, too. Now, if I would take a convex set A, I don't see how can I use erosion on it to get a non-convex set. Every example I try to create ends up the empty set, because the "holes" in B that are suppose to the "holes" in C, make C be all-zero.

Can someone help with a direction to a proof? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Convexity is closed under intersection**) Given a family of convex set $C_i$, where $i\in I$ for some index set $I$, then $\cap_{i\in I}C_i$ is convex.

In other words, the intersection of convex sets are convex.

Proof. Suppose two points $p$ and $q$ are in $\cap_{i\in I}C_i$. That is, for each $i\in I$, $p\in C_i$ and $q\in C_i$. Consider $L$, the line segment between $p$ and $q$. By the definition of convexity, $L\subseteq C_i$. That is $L\subseteq \cap_{i\in I}C_i$. By the definition of convexity again, $\cap_{i\in I}C_i$$ is convex.

(**Convexity is closed under translation**) If $C$ is a convex set, then $C_t=\{x+t\mid x\in C\}$ is also convex.

In other words, if you translate a convex set, you will get a convex set.

Proof is skipped.

(Convexity is closed under erosion) Suppose $A$ is a convex set. Let $B$ be another set. Then the erosion of $A$ by $B$ is convex.

Proof. I will let you figure out given the above two lemmas. Another hint is given in the statement itself, which is, you do not need $B$ to be convex at all.

---

Is the erosion of $A$ by $B$ always empty?

Imagine both $A$ and $B$ are disks centered at the origin. $A$ is a huge while $B$ is a very small. Then the "erosion" by $B$ can only remove a small stripe along the circumference of $A$. The inner part of $A$ will not be "eroded". So the erosion of $A$ by $B$ will keep a significant part of $A$.

You can also check [an example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)#Example).

Comment: I don't think zhat your two statements can be used to proof the statement of he OP. So could you provide a proof?

Comment: In general, I will wait for the OP to respond. Since you asked, however, I will provide a further hint. Try finding a formula for the erosion of A by B so that the first lemma might be applicable.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add here a full answer using @Apass.Jack helpful hints:

Erosion of $A$ by $B$ can be represented as  $\cap_{b\in B} A_{-b}$, meaning a intersection of all sets A translated by $-b$ for all $b$ in $B$.

Given the 2nd lemma - *Convexity is closed under translation*, so all the sets in the intersection are convex. Using that, and the 1st lemma - *Convexity is closed under intersection*, we end up with a convex set :-)

Using this proof it is obvious that B need not be convex set at all, since no matter what is the shape of B, the translation of A by any $-b \in B$ would still be *convex set* if A is convex.

Answer (score 2):

This can be deduced from the definition of the *erosion*. 
According to the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) we define 
$$B_z=\{b+z\mid b\in B\}$$
and the *erosion* of the 'binary image' $A$ by the 'structuring element' $B$ as 
$$A\circleddash  B=\{z \in E\mid B_z\subseteq A\}$$
The symbol $E$ is either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{Z}^n.$

Now assume that $A$ is convex and $z_1, z_2 \in A \circleddash B$ and $z_3$ is on the line between $z_1$ and $z_2.$ We have to show that $z_3 \in A \circleddash B$, which means $B_{z_3}\subseteq A.$

Then there is a  $\lambda_3 \in [0,1]$ such that

$$z_3=\lambda_3 z_1+(1-\lambda_3) z_2.$$

If $t_3 \in B_{z_3}$ then $t_3-z_3  \in B$ and so 
$$t_3-z_3+z_1 \in B_{z_1}\subseteq A$$
$$t_3-z_3+z_2 \in B_{z_2}\subseteq A$$
Because both numbers are in the convex set $A$ and
$$\lambda_3(t_3-z_3+z_1)+(1-\lambda_3)(t_3-z_3+z_2)=t_3$$
we have $t_3 \in A.$ This holds for all $t_3 \in B_{z_3}.$ So $B_{z_3} \subseteq A$ and this implies $z_3 \in A\circleddash B.$ Therefore $A\circleddash B$ is convex.